# How to get an object properties value while next property is being initialized?

Tags: javascript, object, styled-components, jss

While I was trying JSS I need to do something like this:

```
sampleStyle: {
  width: "50px",
  height: this.width
}
```

I have tried several things to work around that problem but none of them satisfy my needs. The closest one I came up with:

```
var rect = {
    width_: undefined,
    height_: undefined,
    set width(w) {
        this.width_ = w
        this.height_ = w
    },
    set height(h) {
        this.width_ = h
        this.height_ = h
    },
    get width() {
        return this.width_
    },
    get height() {
        return this.height_
    }
}
```

I just want to ask you guys why I am getting this.width as undefined for first example and are there any better way to handle that problem ?

Answer (score 3):

You actually just need one getter / setter:

```
sampleStyle: {
  width: "50px",
  get height() { return this.width },
  set height(h) { this.width = h; },
}
```

> why I am getting this.width as undefined for first example and are there any better way to handle that problem ?

Cause `this` is not pointing to the object but to `window` and that doesnt have a width.

And there are a lot ways, see:

[Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 1):

At first sample you're trying to get `width` from global (`window`) context.
You must use `getters/setters` (there are in second example) to work with your local (`object`) context.

Comment: this refers to object itself in first sample not global

Comment: No, you're wrong. Let's try run that: `let sampleStyle = {width: 123, height: this}; console.log(sampleStyle.height)` and you will get `Window` object.

Comment: wow, is it because width is not declared at the moment i tried to get its value and looks outer scope ?

Comment: It's because `this` calling in a his context (and his context is global - `window`) - he doens't know about `width` property in called object. ;)